# Application and service(s) deployment in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am not clear enough yet how Service Fabric allows deployment.
From the applications being created in a single VS solution, let me try to ask with file formats for better understanding.
In a single Visual Studio solution, there are

- a single .sln
- a single .sfproj
- multiple .csproj(s)

As I see these files, multiple services (.csproj files) are bound to a single Service Fabric application (.sfproj file), which is under single solution file (.sln file).
Can I individually deploy a .csproj project to the Service Fabric cluster, or are these now bound to a .sfproj so that I have to deploy multiple services (each created with .csproj and bound to .sfproj) together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is **yes** and **no** at the same time. Let me explain it in detail.

> Can I individually deploy .csproj project to the Service Fabric cluster

The answer is **no** you can't deploy a service - in term of Service Fabric the minimal unit of deployment is the application (the .sfproj one). So no matter what changes you have you still need to deploy the application.

But as we all understand performing a full deployment of all application services is very hard, consumes lots of time and causes lots of disturbance to the cluster. To avoid this massive update, all Service Fabric components have their own versions (you can take a closer look at `ServiceManifest.xml` and `ApplicationManifest.xml`). So each time application is deployed to the cluster, Service Fabric goes through all services included in the application and updates only components that have been changed (i.e. have different version).

This approach allows you to perform updates of very high granularity i.e. you can update only `<Config />` package of the single service.